# Outsider application result share on FB wall - policy

Tags: facebook, share, policy

I've got a simple question, thanks for answering it :)

We are running a web-based application (a game) outside of Facebook, and we would like to let our users to share the results of their game on their Facebook wall trough a Facebook application. Is itt possible to do this due to the Facebook policy? I know that it is possible and easy technically, but the question is that will Facebook allow it in that case if the game is not Facebook based?

Thanks a lot for the answers!

Kind Regards,
Tomi, Hungary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

This is from Facebook platform policy:

> Desktop web games off of Facebook.com may only use Facebook Login
>   (Authentication, excluding user connections such as friend list),
>   Social Plugins and publishing (e.g., Feed Dialog, Stream Publish, or
>   Open Graph).

As you can see the feed dialog is ok.

Read the whole section 1.13 for special policy regarding games in this link https://developers.facebook.com/policy/